# Snowflake get error using NLTK package by using Snowpark framework

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, nltk

I am trying to do text mining on Snowflake by using Python, which need to use NLTK package. But it gave me error like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "nltk/corpus/util.py", line 84, in __load
    root = nltk.data.find(f"{self.subdir}/{zip_name}")
  File "nltk/data.py", line 583, in find
    raise LookupError(resource_not_found)
LookupError: 
**********************************************************************
  Resource [93mwordnet[0m not found.
  Please use the NLTK Downloader to obtain the resource:

  [31m>>> import nltk
  >>> nltk.download('wordnet')
  [0m
  For more information see: https://www.nltk.org/data.html

  Attempted to load [93mcorpora/wordnet.zip/wordnet/[0m

  Searched in:
    - '/home/udf/nltk_data'
    - '/usr/lib/python_udf/60bdac8bd3ab49160e68d1c230dbee4e9fe700de7ef0f3c065830b86356ce449/nltk_data'
    - '/usr/lib/python_udf/60bdac8bd3ab49160e68d1c230dbee4e9fe700de7ef0f3c065830b86356ce449/share/nltk_data'
    - '/usr/lib/python_udf/60bdac8bd3ab49160e68d1c230dbee4e9fe700de7ef0f3c065830b86356ce449/lib/nltk_data'
    - '/usr/share/nltk_data'
    - '/usr/local/share/nltk_data'
    - '/usr/lib/nltk_data'
    - '/usr/local/lib/nltk_data'
**********************************************************************


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  Worksheet, line 19, in main
  Worksheet, line 68, in tokenize
  Worksheet, line 69, in <listcomp>
  File "nltk/stem/wordnet.py", line 45, in lemmatize
    lemmas = wn._morphy(word, pos)
  File "nltk/corpus/util.py", line 121, in __getattr__
    self.__load()
  File "nltk/corpus/util.py", line 86, in __load
    raise e
  File "nltk/corpus/util.py", line 81, in __load
    root = nltk.data.find(f"{self.subdir}/{self.__name}")
  File "nltk/data.py", line 583, in find
    raise LookupError(resource_not_found)
LookupError: 
**********************************************************************
```

however, I already had the

```
import nltk
nltk.download('stopwords')
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
```

in my code. So does anyone can help me where I did wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You are not doing something wrong but rather not supported (as of 07 Aug 2023). Snowpark functions are executed in a sandbox without access to external resources over the Public Internet. Stay tuned...

I haven't tried a specific scenario myself, but I suggest trying to:

1. Manually download the NLTK packages as explained in their [doc](https://www.nltk.org/data.html#manual-installation).
2. Then check this [KB](https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/Importing-3rd-party-Python-packages-containing-non-Python-files-using-Snowflake-stages-when-creating-Python-UDFs) that explains how to use `/tmp` folder to upload your own packages for python UDFs.

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can request for 'external access' that will allow you to reach the internet securely for specific network locations. You can request access through your account rep, while this is in private preview. See here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CXnjvyeb-Q8